# Perl regex substitution using external parameters

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

Consider the following example:

```
my $text = "some_strange_thing";
$text =~ s/some_(\w+)_thing/no_$1_stuff/;
print "Result: $text\n";
```

It prints

> "Result: no_**strange**_stuff"

So far so good.

Now, I need to get both the match and replacement patterns from external sources (user input, config file, etc).
Naive solution appears to be like this:

```
my $match = "some_(\\w+)_thing";
my $repl = "no_\$1_stuff";

my $text = "some_strange_thing";
$text =~ s/$match/$repl/;
print "Result: $text\n";
```

However:

> "Result: no_**$1**_stuff".

What's wrong? How can I get the same outcome with externally supplied patterns?

Comment: Why did you escape `$` in `$repl`? Try this: `my $repl = "no_$1_stuff";`.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh - It should be obvious why that will yield `no__stuff` if you think about it.

Comment: @DanielMartin I do know nothing about strings in Perl. But I know something in regex.

Comment: Tried. Perl says "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution 1: `String::Substitution`**

Use **[`String::Substitution`](http://search.cpan.org/~rwstauner/String-Substitution-1.001/lib/String/Substitution.pm) package**:

```
use String::Substitution qw(gsub_modify);

my $find = 'some_(\w+)_thing';
my $repl = 'no_$1_stuff';
my $text = "some_strange_thing";
gsub_modify($text, $find, $repl);
print $text,"\n";
```

> The replacement string only *interpolates* (term used loosely) numbered match vars (like `$1` or `${12}`). See ["interpolate_match_vars"](http://search.cpan.org/~rwstauner/String-Substitution-1.001/lib/String/Substitution.pm#interpolate_match_vars) for more information.
>   
>   This module does **not** save or interpolate `$&` to avoid the "considerable performance penalty" (see [perlvar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar)).

**Solution 2: `Data::Munge`**

This is a solution mentioned by [Grinnz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268176/perl-regex-substitution-using-external-parameters/31268517?noredirect=1#comment95923649_31268517) in the comments below.

The [`Data::Munge`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING,-REGEX,-REPLACEMENT,-FLAG) can be used the following way:

```
use Data::Munge;

my $find = qr/some_(\w+)_thing/;
my $repl = 'no_$1_stuff';
my $text = 'some_strange_thing';
my $flags = 'g';
print replace($text, $find, $repl, $flags);
# => no_strange_stuff
```

**Solution 3: A quick'n'dirty way (if replacement won't contain double quotes and security is not considered)**

**DISCLAIMER**: *I provide this solution as this approach can be found online, but its caveats are not explained. **Do not use it in production**.*

With this approach, you can't have a replacement string that includes a `"` double quotation mark and, since this is equivalent to handing whoever is writing the configuration file direct code access, it should not be exposed to Web users (as mentioned by [Daniel Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268176/perl-regex-substitution-using-external-parameters/31268517?noredirect=1#comment50533739_31268517)).

You can use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $match = qr"some_(\w+)_thing";
my $repl = '"no_$1_stuff"';
my $text = "some_strange_thing";
$text =~ s/$match/$repl/ee;
print "Result: $text\n";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FiOUww)

Result:

```
Result: no_strange_stuff
```

You have to

1. Declare the replacement in `'"..."'` so as `$1` could be later evaluated
2. Use [`/ee`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) to force the double evaluation of the variables in the replacement.

> A modifier available specifically to search and replace is the `s///e` evaluation modifier. `s///e` treats the replacement text as Perl code, rather than a double-quoted string. The value that the code returns is substituted for the matched substring. `s///e` is useful if you need to do a bit of computation in the process of replacing text.

You can use [`qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) to instantiate pattern for the regex (`qr"some_(\w+)_thing"`).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed /ee and 'quoting' together resolved my issue. 
Can't say I fully understand why the 'quoting' trick works. I tried other stuff like escaping, but apparently I miss something. Can you explain me a bit the logic behind this, please?

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. /e requires "quoted" string and ' ' provides this.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yes, `ee` is necessary to evaluate the RHS twice, once to turn `$repl` into `no_$1_stuff`, then again to turn it into the string "no_$1_stuff" with `$1` as a replacement backreference. There are some resources describing that behavior. See [example description of /ee here](http://www.sthomas.net/roberts-perl-tutorial.htm/ch10/_ee).

Comment: Note that in order to quote in this fashion, you can't have a repl that includes a `"` character. Also, note that this is equivalent to handing whoever is writing the config file direct code access, so don't expose this to web users.

Comment: Just wanted to add that to add a quote to the replacement pattern, one just needs to use an escaped quote, and to use a backslash, 4 backslash symbols must be used (e.g. [`my $repl = '"no_[$1]\\\\_stuff"';`](https://ideone.com/CTJRSI)).

Comment: String::Substitution is definitely the way to go. -1 planting the idea idea that short-and-sweet `/ee` is an option.

Comment: I would also recommend `replace` from [Data::Munge](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#replace-STRING,-REGEX,-REPLACEMENT,-FLAG) as a better option than `/ee` for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same approach as the accepted solution, but I kept the initial lines the same as the problem statement, since I thought that might make it easier to fit into more situations:

```
my $match = "some_(\\w+)_thing";
my $repl = "no_\$1_stuff";

my $qrmatch = qr($match);
my $code = $repl;

$code =~ s/([^"\\]*)(["\\])/$1\\$2/g;
$code = qq["$code"];

if (!defined($code)) {
  die "Couldn't find appropriate quote marks";
}

my $text = "some_strange_thing";
$text =~ s/$qrmatch/$code/ee;
print "Result: $text\n";
```

Note that this works no matter what is in `$repl`, whereas the naive solution has issues if `$repl` contains a double quote character itself, or ends in a backslash.

Also, assuming that you're going to run the three lines at the end (or something like it) in a loop, do make sure that you don't skip the `qr` line. It will make a huge performance difference if you skip the `qr` and just use `s/$match/$code/ee`.

Also, even though it's not as trivial to get arbitrary code execution with this solution as it is with the accepted one, it wouldn't surprise me if it's still possible. In general, I'd avoid solutions based on `s///ee` if the `$match` or `$repl` come from untrusted users. (e.g., don't build a web service out of this)

Doing this kind of replacement securely when `$match` and `$repl` are supplied by untrusted users should be asked as a different question if your use case includes that.

Comment: Thanks! No, source is not webuser. I have multiple filtering options for different projects and wanted to have same scripts for all. The difference is mainly in "patterns" that's why I wanted to have them kept externally.

Comment: `/ee` is super dangerous. Don't use arbitrary Perl code as a template; use an actual template! String::Substitution provides solutions.